# Jasper Report - Marker limitation when exporting Google Map to PDF

Tags: google-maps, jasper-reports

We are using Jasper Reports 7.1 (JR) to plot approx. 100 markers on a Google map.  JR renders the map & markers perfectly however there is a problem when printing to PDF:

- If the **number of markers is 39 or less**, the PDF print will show the **map & markers**, as expected
- If however, the **number of markers is greater than 39**, the PDF print will show the **map only** (i.e. the Markers are excluded)

The PDF printing function is the one provided by JR.  It is used by running the report, then hovering over the report’s “export” icon and clicking “PDF”.

The Jasper Reports Server is version 7.1.1 and is running on a Centos7 virtual machine with 4 cores and 32GB ram.

My question is **how do we overcome this unexpected limit on the number of markers**?

There is an article on the Jaspersoft Community forum ([here](https://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/1035361/marker-limitation-while-exporting-google-map-pdf-jasper-studio-631)) from 2016 referring to a similar problem with Jasper Studio 6.3.1 and a limit of 65 markers, but no solution was provided.

Another article ([here](https://community.jaspersoft.com/jasperreports-server/issues/3395)) from 2014 referring to a limit of or 21 markers on Jasper Reports v5.x.  The problem apparently lies with the PDF writer/exporter.  No solution was provided.

Possible solutions to overcome this limit could include the following, but I’m uncertain of how to progress further:

- Adjusting something on the report
- Reconfiguring the server / PDF    writer
- Upgrading the PDF writer, or replacing it with a “commercial
  version” that has no limits.

Any suggestions to overcome this issue are greatly appreciated.

Comment: It seems that this will be against the [Google Maps Platform Terms of Services 3.2.3 Restrictions Against Misusing the Services](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms#3.-license.). You might want to consider changing the use case for reporting in order to prevent being flagged due to this use case.

Comment: Hi  Shawn Domingo, Thanks for your feedback.  We have read & re-read the Google terms of service, and am not sure which ones we are supposedly breaching? 

Essentially, we are embedding a Google map in a Jasper report, using jasper technology.  It seems like every modern-day reporting system has this technology, but in Jasper's case it does not work correctly.

Could you please expand on why this is in breach.

Comment: Hello, it would fall under `3.2.3 Restrictions Against Misusing the Services. (a) No Scraping` which states "Customer will not export, extract, or otherwise scrape Google Maps Content for use outside the Services." hence, printing the map into the reports might be against the ToS of the Google Maps Platform. I highly suggest that you reach out to the support team of Google Maps APIs to clarify this matter and have them confirm to prevent being flagged in the future. You can reach out to the support team through this [link](https://console.cloud.google.com/google/maps-apis/support).

Comment: Hi @ShawnDomingo 

FYI, we are NOT scraping, but using the Google maps API to generate a map (that we pay for) and then embed this map in a report to show customer locations.  The report is displayed on the user's screen and they can choose to print to paper.  
We are using the same technique described in this Jasper Reports article 
[here](https://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/tibco-jaspersoft-studio-user-guide/v640/working-map-component). In light of your serious allegations, we have followed your advice and submitted a case to Google support for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

We received feedback from Google Maps support as follows::

"Loading Embed Maps on a website and calling the API request every time a map is loaded on your website is compliant to our Platform terms. However, if your application allows users to export Google Maps data/content, then that's a violation to Google Maps Platform terms."

"As stated in this [FAQ](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#tos_export), if your application generates a document, either in electronic or printed form, no data from Google Maps Platform should be included in the document."

With this in mind, we have scrapped the export/ print functionality for this report. Users can only view it on their screen.